# Mimicking classes with structs in C

Tags: beginner, object-oriented, c

I'm trying to mimic classes. Is there anything with this code that I should not do with C or any ways that I can improve it at all, such as best practices or anything?

structs.h

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

typedef struct  {
    char name[30];
    int damage;
    int durability;
} weapon;

typedef struct {
    int health;
    int armor_level;
    int currency;
    weapon player_weap;
} player;

#endif
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "structs.h"

player new_player();
void print_player(player user);

int main(void) {

    player user = new_player();
    print_player(user);

    return 0;
}

player new_player() {

    player new_player;
    new_player.health = 100;
    new_player.armor_level = 0;
    new_player.currency = 0;
    strcpy(new_player.player_weap.name, "Starter Sword");
    new_player.player_weap.damage = 1;
    new_player.player_weap.durability = 100;

    return new_player;

}

void print_player(player user) {
    printf("The players health is %d.\n", user.health);
    printf("The players armor is %d.\n", user.armor_level);
    printf("The players currency is %d.\n", user.currency);
    printf("The players weapon is the %s.\n", user.player_weap.name);
    printf("The players weapon does %d damage and has %d durability.\n", user.player_weap.damage, user.player_weap.durability);
}
```

Comment: Well, which features do you want to support? Inheritance, including multiple and virtual? Late binding, using slots or names? Dynamic type information, including dynamic casting? I'm sure there are more, and different languages embrace their own flavor of their own subset of them.

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty simple and readable as far as it goes, which is *good*. It doesn't do a whole lot but I have some comments that you might consider.

### methods?

It's curious that you mention mimicking classes but there are no function pointers in the structs. In C it's more difficult to get the constructor in there, but `print` could be a function pointer.

```
typedef struct {
    //...
    void (*print)(struct player);
    //...
} player;

player new_player() {
    //...
    new_player.print = print_player;
    //...
}

int main(){
    //...
    user.print(user);
    //...
}
```

### Initializers

C does have a nice initializer syntax, esp. with C99's designators. Your 
constructor function could be somewhat nicer by using the initializer.

```
player new_player() {

    player new_player = {
    .health = 100,
    .armor_level = 0,
    .currency = 0,
    .player_weap = {
        .name = "Starter Sword",
        .damage = 1,
        .durability = 100
        }
    };

    return new_player;
}
```

Or even simpler with a compound literal.

```
player new_player() {
    return (player) {
    .health = 100,
    .armor_level = 0,
    .currency = 0,
    .player_weap = {
        .name = "Starter Sword",
        .damage = 1,
        .durability = 100
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you give me an example of a function pointer in the struct?

Comment: @izzzi https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html

Comment: @izzzi Added illustrative code. pacman's link looks pretty good too.

Comment: The function pointer didnt seem to work with the typedef beacuase `void (*print)(struct player);` needs player not struct player and with just player it couldnt recognize it :/ Works great though if I switch it all back to struct player

Comment: Yes. Good catch. I messed that up a little. This case might work better with `typedef struct player player; struct player { ... };` as two separate statements.

Comment: That worked. But why dos it work? I don't fully understand what it does.

Comment: You can use a struct with a tag before you define it. So `typedef struct player player` just tells the compiler that 'player' means 'struct player'. Then the next declaration tells the compiler what 'struct player' means. If you do the typedef first, then you can use 'player' inside the definition of the struct, at least in the arguments or return type of a function pointer or as a pointer to the same type of thing. This is a good pattern for linked lists or trees.

Answer (score 3):

This question stirred my curiosity about macro handling and the following horrible hack was born: a series of macros for object like structures.

Each "class" is defined in its header file and methods are defined in the corresponding .c file. All objects are passed to functions or returned from functions as pointers. In this way objects can be static, automatic or allocated.

Let's start with *weapon.h*:

```
#if !defined WEAPON_H
#define WEAPON_H

#include "objects.h"

#define CLASS weapon
MEMBERS
    char name[30];
    int damage;
    int durability;
METHODS
    void METHOD(print);
    int  METHOD(get_damage);
    void METHOD(set_damage, int val);
#undef CLASS

#endif // WEAPON_H
```

Note that the class is defined, then members must follow, and later methods. This automatically defines two functions weapon_constructor, weapon_destructor which are responsible to initialize and release every resource of the class. Moreover it also creates new_weapon() which allocates and constructs and delete_weapon() which destroys and frees.

The implementations in *weapon.c* is:

```
#include "weapon.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define CLASS weapon
BEGIN_DEFINITIONS
DEFINE_CONSTRUCTOR
    strcpy(self->name, "Starter Sword");
    self->damage = 1;
    self->durability = 100;
    return self;
DEFINE_DESTRUCTOR
END_DEFINITIONS

void METHOD(print)
{
    printf("The weapon is the %s.\n", self->name);
    printf("The weapon does %d damage and has %d durability.\n", self->damage, self->durability);
}

int METHOD(get_damage)
{
    return self->damage;
}

void METHOD(set_damage, int val)
{
    self->damage = val;
}
```

Ok, what are all those macros? They are defined in *objects.h*:

```
#if !defined OBJECTS_H
#define OBJECTS_H

//Stuff for macro handling (https://github.com/pfultz2/Cloak/wiki/C-Preprocessor-tricks,-tips,-and-idioms)
#define CAT(a, ...) PRIMITIVE_CAT(a, __VA_ARGS__)
#define PRIMITIVE_CAT(a, ...) a ## __VA_ARGS__
// ------------------------------------------------

// Requires a #define CLASS 
#define OPERATOR(name, ...) CAT(name,CAT(_,CLASS))(__VA_ARGS__)
#define METHOD(name, ...) CAT(CLASS,_)##name(CLASS* self, __VA_ARGS__)
#define CALL(self, method, ...) CAT(CLASS,_)##method(self, __VA_ARGS__)

#define CONSTRUCTOR CLASS* METHOD(constructor)
#define DESTRUCTOR  CLASS* METHOD(destructor)
#define NEW         CLASS* OPERATOR(new)
#define DELETE      void OPERATOR(delete, CLASS* obj)

#define MEMBERS typedef struct CLASS {

#define METHODS     \
} CLASS;            \
CONSTRUCTOR; \
DESTRUCTOR;  \
NEW;         \
DELETE;

#define BEGIN_DEFINITIONS
#define DEFINE_CONSTRUCTOR CONSTRUCTOR {
#define DEFINE_DESTRUCTOR return self; } DESTRUCTOR {
#define END_DEFINITIONS return self; }                   \
NEW { return CALL(malloc(sizeof(CLASS)), constructor); } \
DELETE { free(CALL(obj, destructor)); }

// Remember to #undef CLASS 

#endif // OBJECTS_H
```

What about the player? It uses a weapon, so in the constructor it will construct its weapon and in the destructor it will destruct it. *player.h*:

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

#include "objects.h"
#include "weapon.h"

#define CLASS player
MEMBERS
    int health;
    int armor_level;
    int currency;
    weapon weap;
METHODS
    void METHOD(print);
#undef CLASS

#endif // PLAYER_H
```

And the corresponding *player.c*:

```
#include "player.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define CLASS player
BEGIN_DEFINITIONS
DEFINE_CONSTRUCTOR
    self->health = 100;
    self->armor_level = 0;
    self->currency = 0;
    weapon_constructor(&self->weap);
DEFINE_DESTRUCTOR
    weapon_destructor(&self->weap);
END_DEFINITIONS

void METHOD(print)
{
    printf("The player's health is %d.\n", self->health);
    printf("The player's armor is %d.\n", self->armor_level);
    printf("The player's currency is %d.\n", self->currency);
    printf("Player's weapon: ");
    weapon_print(&self->weap);
}
```

Note that in the print method it calls the print method of weapon. All methods get the class name before the method name. Their first parameter is a pointer to the object on which they should work, called self a la Python.

A test case *main.c*:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "player.h"

// Example usage of objects on free store
int main(void) {
    player *user = new_player();

    weapon_set_damage(&user->weap, 2);
    int x = weapon_get_damage(&user->weap);

    player_print(user);

    delete_player(user);
    return 0;
}

/*
// Example usage of objects with automatic storage duration
int main(void) {
    player user;
    player_constructor(&user);

    weapon_set_damage(&user.weap, 2);
    int x = weapon_get_damage(&user.weap);

    player_print(&user);

    player_destructor(&user);
    return 0;
}
*/
```

This is a sample usage. You can follow on this horrible idea by subclassing a player in a simple way: have the first element be an element of the super class. With a little cast you can pass the derived object to the super class methods, without any problem. The problems begin when you start to need polymorphism. In  this case you will definitely need to look into function pointers.

Disclaimer: I'm not supporting this idea as clever or smart. It was just a nice way to spend some time hacking C macros.

Comment: +1 for (yet another) OO macro set abusing the preprocessor.

Comment: Very cool stuff. One part makes me wonder... The `#define CLASS ...` I wonder if it could be reworked to pass this as a parameter to the macros. Maybe something like `defclass(CLASS, VARS, METHODS)`. For reference, I have a [long answer about X-Macros which lies in similar territory,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635851/real-world-use-of-x-macros/6636596#6636596). With the X-macros, passing in the otherwise hidden variable is a clear win IMO.